# How to do display a specific number of result per page in jsp using servlet and jstl

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

would like to get a working example of how to do greedy pagination in jsp. have done something but mine only displays 1 result.

```html
jsp codes

<table id="menDisplayTable">    
            
            <tr id="menTr">
            <c:forEach items="${returnedMenWatches}" var="proDetails">
            <td id="menTd"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${proDetails.mode4}" height="50" width="50"/><br>
                            ${proDetails.brand}<br>
                            ${proDetails.name}<br>
                            ${proDetails.gender}<br>
                            ${proDetails.price}
             </td>
             </c:forEach> 
             </tr>
               
        </table>
```

```html
servlet codes

           int page = 1;
        int recordsPerPage = 10;
        if(request.getParameter("page") !=null)
            page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
        List<Product> returnedMenWatches = connect.getMenWatch();
        int noOfRecords = connect.getNoOfRecords();
        int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
        request.setAttribute("returnedMenWatches", returnedMenWatches);
        request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
        request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("men.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

```html
DAO class 

static int noOfRecords;
     //method to display men products
     public List<Product> getMenWatch() throws SQLException {
         List<Product> returnedMenWatches = new ArrayList<Product>();
         String male = "Male";
         Statement myStatement = getConnection();
         String query = "SELECT Product_ID, Brand, Product_Name, Gender, Product_Price, Product_Picture_Main, COUNT(Product_ID) AS NoOfRecords "
                 + "FROM Products WHERE Gender = '"+male+"'";
         rs = myStatement.executeQuery(query);
         while (rs.next()){
             Product proDetails = new Product();
             proDetails.setProductId(rs.getInt("Product_ID"));
             proDetails.setBrand(rs.getString("Brand"));
             proDetails.setName(rs.getString("Product_Name"));
             proDetails.setGender(rs.getString("Gender"));
             proDetails.setPrice(rs.getFloat("Product_Price"));
             Blob mode1 = rs.getBlob("Product_Picture_Main");
               Blob mode2 = (Blob) mode1;
               byte[]mode3 = mode2.getBytes(1, (int)mode2.length());
               String mode4 = Base64.encode(mode3);
             proDetails.setMode4(mode4);
             noOfRecords = rs.getInt("NoOfRecords");
             returnedMenWatches.add(proDetails);
         }
         return returnedMenWatches;
     }
     // method to get number of records returned from the get men watches query 
     public int getNoOfRecords() {
        return noOfRecords;
    }
```

please i need your help, thanks in advance. 
have don some editing, i added the DAO code where sql query is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `<c:foreach....` before `<tr>` tag to repeat table rows.

Comment: please share your changes

Comment: i changed this List<Product> returnedMenWatches = connect.getMenWatch((page-1)*recordsPerPage, recordsPerPage); to this List<Product> returnedMenWatches = connect.getMenWatch();

Answer (score 0):

Change your jsp code like this to add `<tr>` tag in each iteration of your `forEach`.

```
<table id="menDisplayTable">    


                <c:forEach items="${returnedMenWatches}" var="proDetails">
                <tr>
                <td id="menTd"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${proDetails.mode4}" height="50" width="50"/><br>
                                ${proDetails.brand}<br>
                                ${proDetails.name}<br>
                                ${proDetails.gender}<br>
                                ${proDetails.price}
                 </td>
                 </tr>
                 </c:forEach> 


            </table>
```

It should work.

Comment: hi, thanks for your contribution, but i tried it, it didnt work.

Comment: share page source with us.